# Build project to run it in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

My code runs a previous version of itself, so even though i completely remove all the code, it still runs the old one. I've read a few other posts regarding this problem, and tried it out. My temporary solution is to build the project before running it, but that is kinda stupid. the .exe file is in the Release folder, and my Debug folder dissapeared after the Clean.

How do I stop needing to build the project before everytime I need to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out there's a button called auto build in the Launch Configuration properties window. So it build everytime I run it.